# Trying to get property of non-object foreach blade in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, controller, laravel-blade

I am trying to access my course information from a foreach, but it shows this error: Trying to get property of non-object.

I tried to access the information as follows: `$purchase->course->name`
also like this:
`$ purchase[course][name]` but does not show any results, I have attached my model, my controller and my view.

Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{   
    protected $fillable = [
            'transaction_id',
            'user_id',
            'course_id',
            'status',
            'total'
    ];

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class,'course_id');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Purchase;

class PurchaseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {  
        $purchases = Purchase::with('courses')->get();
        return view('purchases.index',compact('purchases'));
    }
}
```

View:

```php
@foreach($purchases as $purchase )
 {{$purchase->course->name}}
@endforeach
```

if show only the variable like this `$purchase` all the data appears but when trying to access the course `$purchase->course` it shows nothing. 
In the controller it works fine only not works in blade view.

Comment: change ` {{$purchase->course->name}}` to `{{$purchase->courses->name}}`. Your relationship name is `courses` but you'r using `course`.

Comment: Or you could change the method name to a singular form since you are dealing with many-to-one. `public function course()` then in your controller: `$purchases = Purchase::with('course')->get();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{ $purchase->course->name }}
```

Should be:

```
{{ $purchase->courses->name }}
```

Your function name is courses() which means the attribute name is `courses`, not `course`.

Comment: Oh man, thanks, I hadn't seen that, now I feel a little silly haha

Comment: Always good to get a second set of eyes -- sometimes the most annoying bugs are the simplest to fix in retrospect